# Make a polygon have smooth edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a large array of x and y coordinates from which I'm drawing an SVG polygon. For some points, the change in gradient of the line is very small, but I'm still getting a jagged "corner" where the two lines meet. How can I make it have smoothed out corners?

Preferably, this wouldn't kick in when the change in gradient is large (a 90 degree angle for example). So, one polygon could have some corners smoothed out, but where the angle is very different to 180 (180 = no change in gradient), the corners would remain sharp.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you tried?

Comment: @Neal I am aware of D3's interpolation feature, but I'm not sure how it can be applied to polygons, only lines (or how to make it apply to some corners but not others). Other than that, I don't have any good ideas.

Comment: Create a path instead and draw the corners as bezier curves.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'd like the polygon to be filled, though.